# Spring Boot, How to Validation (@Notblank) json array in request

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi everyone I have a question about validate json array request in Spring Boot

**This controller**

```
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> humanController(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> header,@Valid @RequestBody jsonRequest rqBody) throws ServiceException,Exception {
  ...

  ...

}
```

**This jsonRequest Model Request**

```
public class jsonRequest {

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "body")
    private bodyModel[] body;

 ...

 ...
}
```

**This bodyModel Request**

```
public class bodyModel {
    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "hands")
    private String hands;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "legs")
    private String legs;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(value = "head")
    private String head;

    ...

    ...
}
```

How can I validate (@Notblank) in bodyModel, I use @NotBlank It not work ?

Comment: try to switch `body` from array of bodyModel to a List

Comment: @ShaharT I have try to change "private bodyModel[] body;" to "private list<bodyModel> body;" It's still not validate value in class bodyModel.

Comment: List<@Valid bodyModel>. By the way, you should rename bodyModel to BodyModel (Java's convention for class name)